# Get C# to respect \n returned in a string from a web service?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I have a messaging system that is a .NET 2 ASMX web service, very basic system.  I push messages and would like to have newline symbols in the message so it's formatted on the receiving end.  For example, I'd like to send a string such as:  "Hello\n\nMy Name Is..." and have it have two line breaks.  When the receiver reads the text it's actually outputting the \n's in the text.  How can I get the \n's to be interpreted as if I was writing it in C#?  Or \t etc.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried sending \r\n instead?

Comment: How is the 'receiving end' outputting the text?

Comment: It sounds like your string is being escaped somewhere along the way. Have you looked at the raw text in a debugger or somwhere? I suspect you'll see either C# or html escaping in the raw text. Either way it should be simple enoungh to unescape it on the client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should compose the message using **Environment.NewLine** to insert the character(s) used to  represent a newline on your system.

[See here for references](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx)

However using Environment.NewLine has some problems.
For example, your message should be written in this way

```
string msg = "Hello" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "My Name Is...";
```

a bit cumbersome to use from a programmer point of view.

Then you could write an extension method for the string class which takes your message and insert at the place of a placeholder the Environment.NewLine chars.

This example use the | (pipe) character as placeholder for the newline pos.

```
public static string InsertLineBreaks(this string inMsg)
{
    Strinbuilder sb = new StringBuilder(inMsg);
    sb.Replace("|", Environment.NewLine);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

and you can call this extension in this way

```
string msg = "Hello||My Name Is...".InsertLineBreaks();
```

Comment: That will only work if the receiving environment is the same, which can't be guaranteed by the service, right?

Comment: @RJLohan given the tags I suppose that this was the case. However waiting for clarification from the OP

Comment: it can make help in stored templates, can replace like `MessageBody.Replace("{{newline}}", Environment.NewLine)` ;)

Answer (score 1):

The web service is likely sending the message back with carriage returns listed as "%0D".  What I have done in my programs is use:

```
str.Replace("%0D", Environment.NewLine);
```

That seems to work for me.

I'm sure you could also use:

```
str.Replace("%0D", "\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace the `\n` with something that is interpreted as a new line by the browser, i.e. `<br/>`. I suppose you're using it as an HTML string.

Besides you need to get sure that it isn't HtmlEncoded, i.e., that your `<br/>` isn't converted into `&lt;br/&gt;`. This shouldn't happend if you're using JSON serialization. but will happen if you serialize it as XML and isn't properly decoded in client side.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
string returnString = "Hello" + Environment.NewLine+ "My Name Is..";
```